# Adding fields to user registration form

Tags: users

I want to collect user personal information like first name, last name, and home address in in user registration, and I also want user to make the profile pubic or private.

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: and this doesn't do what you want? http://drupal.org/project/profile2

Comment: I don't think you need any additional modules (like profile2) to achieve this. It's a bit buried in D7, but if you go to admin/config/people/accounts and click on "Manage Fields" you'll be able to add fields to user accounts just like you would for node types, taxonomy vocabularies, etc.

Comment: Why don't you use Profile2 module? you can save privacy. Also you can force the users to fill profile fields. profile2 project page in drupal.org is "https://drupal.org/project/profile2"

Comment: Noticed a bunch of retags on this.  Please note that version tags should be used only for questions that apply to a version only, not to merely say what version a site is using.

Comment: how can i display the filed only to the admin not for frontend ?

Answer (score 12):

Go to Config > People > Account Settings > Manage Fields

Then, you can add fields to user profiles just as you would add fields to any content type. When you add fields here, there is a checkbox to "Display on user registration form" if you want the field to be part of the user's registration process.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Shouldnt this create a table  like  "field_data_field_custom_field"?  if not where is that stored?  I made a few custom fields but cannot find them in my database

Answer (score 4):

You can add fields by going to `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` then set the privacy settings of those fields with an access control module like Field Permissions

http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Comment: Little gotcha here - make sure you have the Field UI module enabled, otherwise this tab won't show up. I usually disable UIs on production sites (like Views, Rules, Fields UI etc) and sometimes it takes me a bit to remember this needs to be enabled to access this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add fields to "Create Account" registration form, you can do this in following way:

Go to "--/admin/config/people/accounts/fields" then while "Add new field". While adding new field, under label you could see "Display on user registration form". Check this box and the corresponding field will be shown on registration form.

Answer (score 0):

From Drupal 8 you can easily drag and drop that field within the /user/register form. Up , down, visible, invisible. Super cool!

Link: `"/admin/config/people/accounts/form-display/register"`