# Added fields are not displaying while creating the user

Tags: users

I am new to drupal and I have added few more necessary fields to the user create page [i,e in configuration->people->account setting->manage fields],but the added fields are not displaying while creating the user[i,e admin->people->add user]
but its **displaying while editing the created user**, I have searched to figure it out from last 1 week but no luck for me. if anyone know the reason for not displaying please help me. I have attached the screen shot too.Thanks in advance.

[image: the added fields are not dispalying]

[image: Fields has been added]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a similar questions on Drupal answers. I would remove this one as i considered duplicated.

[Adding fields to user registration form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59079/adding-fields-to-user-registration-form)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your problem is that you are missing an option while saving new fields. Please must tick the check-box **"Display on user registration form"** placed below the **"label"** field as shown below in the image.

[image]